In TNG: the Pegasus, why is Geordi in the first meeting with the Admiral?
Once Pressman comes aboard the enterprise there is a meeting. Picard and Riker are obvious choices to attend but why was Geordi there? It isn't obvious that the Pegasus has advanced technology until that meeting and Data is as capable as Geordi in technical things plus is third in command. So why him?

They are attempting to, at lease, salvage a highly damaged ship, it makes sense to include the Chief Engineer for his input regardless of any advanced tech.

+1 @Paulie_D Pretty sure engineers are indispensable when dealing with old-timey, out-of-date tech also.

Given that LeVar Burton directed the episode, I'm astounded that he isn't in every scene.

@Valorum Ha; given that he directed the episode, I'm astounded he was in any scene at all! Directing's hard enough when you're not also acting. :D

@Idran - Directors always put themselves into things. They can't resist it. Writers are worse although. They make themselves the main character; https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=IiN8mjRx78s

As Chief Engineer, LaForge is in charge of the Engineering staff. He needs to be part of this meeting to learn how many of his staff will be required for the Pegasus task (even without the secret tech, recovery of a lost ship will surely involve engineering), and to provide initial estimates of time required, and tradeoffs regarding other work that may need to be delayed.
Quoting Memory Alpha

The chief engineer's duties ranged from making the duty shift roster
for engineering personnel to advising the captain on possible
solutions for certain technical problems.

All that is relevant to the Pegasus situation, so LaForge belongs at that meeting.
